# callback option for JSON.parse() function in Node.js?

Tags: node.js, mqtt

I have an MQTT message bus/queue that controls a number of things in my Home Automation schema.  One of the things I have in an 'Alert' system that alerts me when something is wrong.  One function of my alert system is to let me know when the wind speed is over a certain limit at the house.  My problem is that the alert code sends me bogus alerts that show wind speeds that are in the hundreds, when in fact they are (usually) below 20 MPH.  Here is the code:

```
client.on('message', function(topic, msg) {
  if(topic.indexOf('wind') != -1) {
    var rr = JSON.parse(msg.toString());
    if(rr.speed > TOPSPEED) {
      notify.notify({
        title: '--ALERT!-- High Winds',
        message: 'Wind speed of ' + rr.speed + ' MPH was just recorded.',
        sound: "Sosumi"
      }, function(err,rsp) {
        // do nothing...we don't care if it error'd, or there was a response.
      });
    }
  } else {...
```

so pretty straight forward:  If the incoming MQTT message has a 'wind' topic, I parse out the payload and look for the 'speed' field...if it's over the TOPSPEED value, then I send out the alert.  The issue is that I have watched the 'speed' values be below the TOPSPEED value, but alerts get sent out indicated a wind speed way over what TOPSPEED is set to...not sure how that is happening.

I was thinking that if there was a way that JSON.parse() had a callback, then I could be sure only one message was being considered for the comparison.  I don't see how multiple speeds could be 'added', but I can't explain the behavior either, unless you add up multiple past wind speeds.

Here is a sample of the MQTT message stream where I got an alert of 105MPH wind speed, yet the values don't add up to that value?!?

```
wind/speed {"name": "Out2", "speed": 9.75 }
wind/dir {"name": "Out2", "dir": "NE" }
wind/speed {"name": "Out2", "speed": 9.75 }
wind/dir {"name": "Out2", "dir": "NE" }
wind/speed {"name": "Out2", "speed": 10.50 }
wind/dir {"name": "Out2", "dir": "NE" }
wind/speed {"name": "Out2", "speed": 7.50 }
wind/dir {"name": "Out2", "dir": "NE" }
wind/speed {"name": "Out2", "speed": 9.75 }
wind/dir {"name": "Out2", "dir": "ENE" }
wind/speed {"name": "Out2", "speed": 10.50 }
```

Any suggestions about what is going wrong?  Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

> wind/speed {"name": "Out2", "speed": 9.75 }
>
> wind/dir {"name": "Out2", "dir": "NE" }
>
> var rr = JSON.parse(msg.toString());

Why are you passing the whole message into the parser?  You should have substring-ed out the prefix or better yet, the prefix should actually be part of the JSON data.
i.e.

```
{"type" : "wind", "attribute" : "speed", "name": "Out2", "speed": 9.75 }
{"type" : "wind", "attribute" : "dir", "name": "Out2", "dir": "NE" }
```

> if(topic.indexOf('wind') != -1)

The other issue is that only half of your JSON data packets actually have 'speed' but you are testing ('if') for 'speed' on every single message.  You should be checking for 'wind/speed' not just 'wind'.

Comment: I'm not....only the JSON part goes into JSON.parse(), and only the "speed" line at that.  I just snagged some debug output to show the speed values, and how they don't add up to 105.  Sorry for not being clear.